# How do I hide default power plans from system tray notification area?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

I have a couple of **custom** power schema's that I want to switch between. 
The system tray notification area should perfectly fit, since it has two places, however i cannot get both of my plans in the battery system tray notification area - whenever i change active power plan to any of my custom plans, remaining place is being taken by one of three default power plans (balanced, max energy, or power saving). Is there a way to get round this limitation and make two custom power plans appear in the notification area?

**P.S.** Presumably i DON't want to delete default system power plans, since it's not quite sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first entry must be a scheme based on "Balanced" the second must be a scheme based on "Power Saver" or "High Performance" (when you create a power scheme you can be "based" on one of those three). Meaning you can not put two power schemes in the notification area that for example are based on "Balanced".

[image]

To replace it (you probable know this):
Choose the power scheme the taskbar you want to replace e.g. "Balanced" 
then click on "More power option" and choose what a power plan you want to use instead of "Balanced" (again if choosing a custom plan, it must be a plan that was "based" on balance). After clicking ok (closing the window) you will see that "Balacend" on the taskbar has been replaced by the custom power scheme.